# Web service method issue. Request never reaches Web Service method (No error)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, soap

OK, I have written a method inside a web service for sending an email (not important).

Site side, i am deserializing a MailMessage object into XML (a custom routine i've written). This then gets passed as a parameter to the web method in the Web service. It all works fine, until a file attachment in the mail message becomes greater than around 144kb.

The XML string for the mail message ends up looking something like this (passed as a unformatted string parameter):

```
    <MailMessage>
      <To>xx.xx@Domain.com</To>
      <From>NoReply@Domain.com</From>
      <Body>blah blah</Body>
      <Attachment ContentType="application/vnd.ms-excel" fileName="Test.xls">
        <byte>00</byte>
        <byte>05</byte>
        <byte>6F</byte>
        …etc
```

The highest attachment size i can succesfully receive is 144kb, anything higher than this, and the request never reaches the web service method. I know this for a fact as the first line in my web method is to log that the request was received. IIS logs show POST messages being received by the webservice (from what i can gather), yet there is no evidence of it arriving inside my web method. There are no errors, despite try catch blocks around everything i can think of.

Is there some sort of default maximum size/timeout that i'm not aware of? I'm no guru with this sort of stuff, so I imagine I am missing something trivial here.

Can anyone advise what I may be doing wrong please? I can post code examples if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increasing the value of maxMessageLength in your web.config should allow for larger soap messages to be passed to the server.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxMessageLength="409600"
    executionTimeoutInSeconds="300"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

See this link for details.

[Large Soap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa528822.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, using the information in the link, I installed WSE and configured my service to use it. All is now working fine.